# Free animation software? (replacement for Flash MX)

Tags: video, flash, animation

a few years ago, I use to love to make animations with Flash MX. Well, now I have the itch to make some animations but I no longer use Windows(now use OpenBSD) and also I've lost my copy of Flash somewhere.. (and no, I don't want to spend a ton of money to buy a new copy)

So now I'm looking for something capable of creating animations that is free and open source. Does anyone know of such a program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synfig

http://synfig.org/

A professional quality open source animation studio. Uses SVG instead of flash and can output to several video formats.

Comment: Here's a demo reel: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eK2DMBkd09I

Looks like you can make some pretty awesome stuff with it :)

Answer (score 2):

I use [Pencil2d](https://www.pencil2d.org/)

It's open source, works on mac, windows and linux.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use blender to render 3d animations.  Though this will take a fair amount of time to set up as well as to render.  www.blender.org

Comment: Not really a Flash replacement at all. Flash is 2D.